# Uploading image to a Spring-Boot web server from android

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am using retrofit 2 library to send image from android device to a server which runs on Spring - Boot. 
I want to simply send an image to see, if all is ok, so i perform this simple type of request:

On server side my controller looks like this:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/updatePhoto" )
public String updateUserPhoto(@RequestPart(name = "img") MultipartFile img) {
    {
        System.out.println("Request  update photo "+ img.getOriginalFilename());
        return "OK";
    }
```

This is my request

```
@POST("/updatePhoto")
@Multipart
Call<String> updateUserPhoto(@Part MultipartBody.Part img);
```

This is how i perform it:

```
 File file = new File(mediaPath);
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);


        System.err.println(filename+"  " + fileToUpload);
        MainAplication.getServerRequests().updateUserPhoto(fileToUpload)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        if(response.body()!=null){
                            System.err.println(response.body());
                        }else{
                            System.err.println("RESPONSE BODY NULL");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        System.err.println("UPDATE PHOTO FAIL " +t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

But every time i try to send an image, my server throws an exception :

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'img' is not present
```

And can`t understand where i`m doing wrong, i had  tried a lot, but a can`t solve this problem. Any ideas what must i improve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this "img" instead of "file"

```
 RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
 MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked!) Many thanks) 
Could you explain in two words, what was the problem, and why using "img" istead of "file" fixed it

Comment: it seems the issue has accepted some answer, is it still not resolved, whats the issue?